# NetworkManager broken after upgrade to Kubuntu Saucy

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, network-manager

I had Kubuntu 13.04 on my ThinkPad X220, and I upgraded to 13.10 and I am not able to connect to a wired or wireless connection. The new network tray icon does not show any entries at all.

In the menu of the tray icon, there is an error saying:

> Require NetworkManager 0.9.8, found .

I then tried the following:

### nmcli con

```
** (process:3695): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.64" (uid=1000 pid=3695 comm="nmcli con ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=1116 comm="NetworkManager ")
Error: nmcli (0.9.8.0) and NetworkManager (unknown) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable.
```

### nmcli dev

```
** (process:3700): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.65" (uid=1000 pid=3700 comm="nmcli dev ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=1116 comm="NetworkManager ")
Error: nmcli (0.9.8.0) and NetworkManager (unknown) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable.
```

### nm-tool

```
** (process:3705): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.66" (uid=1000 pid=3705 comm="nm-tool ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=1116 comm="NetworkManager ")

NetworkManager Tool

State: unknown


** (process:3705): WARNING **: error: could not connect to NetworkManager
```

Running those as root works, however. I was also able to run `nmcli con up id DHCP` which got my `DHCP` connection working and giving me internet access. That did not work using a Wifi connection though, and I do need those.

How can I get networking back to work without a reinstall?

Comment: is network-manager service running? (sudo service network-manager status)

Comment: @OhadCohen: `network-manager start/running, process 995`

Comment: have you tried nmcli with --nocheck option as the error message suggest? what happens when you run nmcli as root (with sudo)?

Comment: @OhadCohen As I wrote in the text, it works with root for wired connections, but not for wireless ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing your [other problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365580/cannot-shut-down-from-kde-workspace-after-upgrade-to-saucy), I'm pretty sure the problem is with [policykit](https://wiki.debian.org/PolicyKit) or consolekit.

make sure you have *policykit-1, policykit-desktop-privileges, polkit-kde-1 and consolekit* installed, by running:

```
sudo apt install policykit-1 policykit-desktop-privileges polkit-kde-1 consolekit
```

if they are installed try reconfiguring them

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure policykit-1 policykit-desktop-privileges consolekit polkit-kde-1
```

Answer (score 4):

If the root user can do something that you can't, it hints towards an issue with the policykit privileges.

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run

```
sudo service network-manager status //Note the process-id (995 in your case as per the comment)
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager status //See if it's still running; if not, enter next command
sudo dpkg-reconfigure policykit-1 policykit-desktop-privileges consolekit polkit-kde-1
```

to reconfigure them.

Then run

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and see if it's working now.

As for the WLAN/WiFi not working even as root (if the issue is still unresolved), please update the Q with the WLAN NIC name. The drivers may be faulty and you may require alternate ones.