# Flash Player Issue In Chromium In Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, chromium, jre

I needed to download youtube videos and it asked to download plugin from Java website.

> Adobe Flash Player is required to display some elements on this page.
>   Install plug-in.

I downloaded this. [jre-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html) but i don't know how to install it. Please tell me how to install it or tell me if there is any fix for this.

Comment: You need the Browser plugin I suppose

Answer (score 0):

You can just install OpenJRE from terminal by running:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

or by clicking icon below

[image: Install soundconverter]

**Edit**

Chromium used Netscape Plugin API for Flash support. Starting from Ubuntu 14.04, Chromium will stop using Netscape Plugin API.

To fix this issue, You need to install Adobe Flash Player installer Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, Running like this:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree

sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

This installer downloads Google Chrome, extracts Pepper Flash Player and sets it up for Chromium usage.

Comment: Its already installed.

Comment: Have you install flash-player like this: `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` BTW, what browser you are using?

Comment: Chromium and flash player is installed.

Comment: It downloaded some deb file. No change in chromium.

Comment: Good. Let me know your progress :)

Comment: i cant see the deb file.

Answer (score 0):

Installing only JRE will not help you to install every kind of java based application try following:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: It says " Already the newest version ! "

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the java runtime. See this question instead [Chromium 34 and later cannot detect flash plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449103)

Answer (score 0):

To install flash player , try using **Pepper Flash Player for Chromium**.

Install as per following steps.

1> To add the PPA and install Adobe Pepper Flash from Google Chrome in Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

2> you need to open /etc/chromium-browser/default as root, for root (open in any editor e.g.:- nano or gedit)

```
sudo -i

gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

or

```
nano /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

paste the following line at the bottom of the file (after the CHROMIUM_FLAGS="" line):

```
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

**Note:- there's a dot in the beginning of the line, then a space!**

3> Restart Chromium browser & visit **chrome://plugins**. you will notice Adobe Flash Player of latest version.