# Chromium not seeing pepperflashplugin-nonfree

Tags: flash, chromium

I've just upgraded to XUbuntu 14.04. I installed Chroimum(chromium-browser package, not Google Chrome). Then installed by running:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

However if I try to load a flash element it still says it isn't installed and it doesn't appear under the chrome://plugins page either.

Running sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status returns this:

```
Flash Player version installed on this system  : 13.0.0.214
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 12.0.0.77
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chromium 34 can't detect flash plugin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-cant-detect-flash-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what happened, but Chromium just randomly crashed, then when I started it again, it worked(I had restarted after installing), maybe it was just taking a while.