# Firefox will play videos of this website but Chromium won't

Tags: flash

The website is [SBS OnDemand](http://www.sbs.com.au/ondemand) in Australia. When there is a program that I want to watch, I know that it **won't** work in Chrome, **won't** work in Chromium, **probably will** work in Firefox, and when Firefox doesn't work, I use Chrome in Windows XP in VirtualBox (which also, very occasionally, won't play the video).

The website video uses Adobe Flash Player. The browsers use the following versions of Flash Player:

- Firefox: 11.2.202.378
- Chromium: 13.0.0.206
- Chrome: 14.0.0.125
- VirtualBox>Windows XP>Chrome: 14.0.0.125

Why would Firefox (using older version of Flash Player) work, while Chromium and Chrome don't? I ask this question purely out of curiosity. It's been occurring for a year or two on several different computers using various Linux distros, so I'd love to get to the bottom of it. My main computer uses Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Odd, [they say different](http://www.sbs.com.au/ondemand/help/#faq_53) - the videos [don't work outside Australia](http://www.sbs.com.au/ondemand/help/#faq_19) anyway. Anyway, what versions of the browsers are you using?

Comment: Yes I have seen "We have found that Google Chrome works most effectively with Linux" but that's exactly wrong in my experience. I imagine that the videos are geo-blocked, which is why I mentioned Australia in the question. Currently: Chromium 34.0.1847.116 (Developer Build 260972) Ubuntu 14.04 aura, Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 (Official Build 274914), Firefox 30.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical 1.0, VirtualBox>Windows XP>Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 (Official Build 274914) m

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-and-later-cannot-detect-flash-plugin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I still had the problem, even when I had installed the PepperFlashPlugin.

Since then, it has started working. ie. I have been able to play videos on that website.

The only difference between then and now is that I now have broadband internet (ie. > 15Mbps). Previously, I only had ADSL (~3Mbps/864kbps)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Chromium have now changed to PepperFlashPlugin to run all flash and while it seems to be a newer version, has quite a few problems when playing content on certain sites and providing hardware acceleration for streaming videos on certain vide cards...

Personally I prefer Firefox because of the fact it still works with the original flash plugin and gives my much needed hardware support and seems that bit more stable...

Answer (score -1):

This solution has worked for me . Try it and see if it does for you . 
Go to software centre and remove chromium and all its plug ins . Open your firefox and follow this link https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/ . Once its downloaded open it with software centre and instal it . That installs Google Chrome stable for 64bit Ubuntu , not that crap that chromium is . All flash video works for me now ( FB , Youtube , et.. )