# Some Youtube videos won't play in Kubuntu 14.04 and Chromium 36.0.1985.125

Tags: video, flash, chromium, ffmpeg

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 and Chromium 36.0.1985.125. I'm finding that some YouTube videos give me the error:

> The Adobe Flash Player is required for video playback.

But most other videos work fine.

I have the "extra" codecs installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'chromium-codecs-ffmpeg' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

For comparison, I installed the latest version of Firefox with Flash and the same videos that won't play in Chromium play fine in Firefox.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chromium 34 can't detect flash plugin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-cant-detect-flash-plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install pepperflash for chromium now because it nolonger accepts netscape like plugins (the firefox flashplugin)

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

restart chromium after installation for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Read https://www.youtube.com/html5. Notice how it says only supported videos will be played in HTML5. However, some videos just require Adobe Flash Player. One thing you could try is clicking "Request the HTML5 player" if it is displayed on that page, then try again. If it still doesn't work or you don't see that button, you need Adobe Flash Player.

Answer (score 0):

There are some videos that stopped playing properly a few days ago yet if you hover over the loading bar it will show a screenshot of the video so the video is there but it winds up saying "There was an error with this video".

The answer just came to me!  It might be it doesn't like ad block.