# Youtube videos don't play on Facebook. (Chromium)

Tags: video, chromium, youtube, facebook

I just started using chromium on ubuntu 14.04 and I went on my Facebook profile page and wanted to start a video that I posted there from youtube and saw that it didn't work. It says that a plugin for this video is missing. here is the screen shot to.

http://s29.postimg.org/skvnhe6jr/Screenshot_from_2014_08_11_02_14_38.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-cant-detect-flash-plugin