# flash player doesn't work on chromium

Tags: flash, chromium, plugins, adobe

I have upgraded to 14.04LTS and my flash player doesn't work on **chromium facebook** **only!!!** It is the latest version of adobe, and works on you tube, as well as with firefox facebook.
Am I missing something here???

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: "This plug-in is not supported" or "upgrade your flash player"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chromium 34 and later cannot detect flash plugin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-and-later-cannot-detect-flash-plugin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chromium, such as Chrome, recently dropped support for NPAPI (Netscape Plugin API) plugins, when they introduced their new Pepper Plugin API (PPAPI). So most older plugins don't work any more, including Adobe Flash Player.

To get Flash back, you have to use Google's own Flash Player called Pepper Flash. In Chrome, it's installed automatically. But not in Chromium, since Pepper Flash is a close-source project by Google.

To install Pepper Flash for Chromium, install the package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`.

The fact that it works with YouTube is because YouTube doesn't use Flash any more. Where possible, it now uses the HTML5 video tag, and only uses Flash as a fallback for older browsers.

Comment: Problem solved with Pepper Flash; can't vote up just yet...