# Flash player not detected for some sites and youtube videos in Chromium

Tags: 14.04, flash, chromium, plugins

I'm following below instructions
[Chromium 34 and later cannot detect flash plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-and-later-cannot-detect-flash-plugin)
But in some Youtube videos I got `The adobe flash player is required for video playback` and some website show the same error.
I've installed latest update of Chromium and Ubuntu and Flash player.

I run `sudo apt-get install  pepperflashplugin-nonfree` then `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install` (after I run it, have no echo), Then I run `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status` (No answer again), additionally When I go to `chrome://plugins`

Comment: Are you using pepperflash plugin?

Comment: @enzotib Yes, I with `sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer` and add `. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh`

Comment: The package `pepflashplugin-installer` does not exist, its name is `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. Also, the file `/usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh` does not exist. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @enzotib Thanks for your attention. I'm using latest version 14.04

Comment: @enzotib Excuse me, Can you open http://speedtest.net with Chromium?

Comment: yes, I can, with pepper flash installed. Try to `sudo apt-get remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, then reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

Comment: @enzotib sorry again! Could you please help me more? I run `sudo apt-get install  pepperflashplugin-nonfree` then `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install` (after I run it, have no echo), Then I run `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status` (No answer again), additionally When I go to `chrome://plugins` There is no any flash plugin.

Comment: If the first two commands didn't work, then something went wrong. Can you run `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install --verbose`?

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thanks for your attention. The result is: options :  `--install --verbose --
temporary directory: /tmp/pepperflashplugin-nonfree.hpZvYvMrgp
doing apt-get update on google repository`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My guess is that it can't contact the Google repository for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install pepperflash for chromium now because it no longer accepts Netscape like plug-ins (the Firefox flash plug-in)

`sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

Restart chromium after installation for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium does not support flash at all anymore. If you want to use flash content, you need to use another browser like Google Chrome or Firefox. Google Chrome has flash support built in, while Firefox requires the package `flashplugin-installer` to be installed to work.

Pepperflash does in my experience work sometimes, but not always.