# chromium 37.0 cannot detect flash player in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: flash, chromium, 14.10

I follow this question [Chromium 34 and later cannot detect flash plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-and-later-cannot-detect-flash-plugin)

and also install **pepper flash plugin** by using this command *sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree* but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

If this doesn’t work you may need to manually configure Chromium. With Chromium fully closed/exited, run the following command in a Terminal to launch the appropriate file in a text editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

Add the following line at the end on a new line:

```
. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

Save and then close. 
Launch Chromium and it should work.

I found this trick on [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/install-pepper-flash-chromium-ubuntu-14-04) and it worked for me.