# Ubuntu Chrome can't load official adobe flash player?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash, adobe

I'm currently using chrome 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04. But i have encoding and massy codes problem when flash contains Chinese words.(This only happens in chrome, firefox in my ubuntu works just fine, but i want to use chrome)

So i turned to official adobe flash plugin and follow this [instruction](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-google-chrome.html#id_27949) on adobe official website.

But after this, i still can only see libpepperflash in chrome://plugins, but i can't see the flash i just installed. How could i fix this?

Comment: Chrome/chromium no longer supports netscape plugins.

Comment: Then is there any other way to solve my messy codes problem?

Comment: If you're using 16.10 and you found this you may want to see [this question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/845328/29097).

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's version of Flash plugin (Adobe does not support Chromium at Linux anymore).

Here's How To: [Chromium 34 and later cannot detect flash plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449103/chromium-34-and-later-cannot-detect-flash-plugin/449266#449266)

Also: [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) has this plugin built-in.

Comment: Chrome no longer has this plugin built in.

Comment: It looks like it's still there, just changed to click-to-run by default from current stable (54.0.2840), couple of weeks earlier than planned though.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/845328/29097

Comment: "In December, Chrome 55 will make HTML5 the default experience, except for sites which only support Flash. For those, you’ll be prompted to enable Flash when you first visit the site." - from the first link in your answer. Not removed, just disabled by default. And not now, but will be somewhen in December. My up-to-date current stable Chrome still have Flash plugin today.