# Using Chromium 53, I get on flash applets: `Couldn't load plugin`

Tags: google-chrome, flash, pepperflash

On every website I get `Couldn't load plugin.`, how do I resolve this? It just started happening in late October. I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and Chromium 53. Pandora also fails to load, *In order to use Pandora internet radio, please install Adobe Flash (v.10 or later).*

[image: Picture of flash not loading]

Comment: I'm removing the 16.10 tag, since if Google Chrome itself has stopped bundling Flash, this will likely affect earlier versions too.

Comment: @muru sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because on October 2016, [Chrome 53, Chrome stopped bundling the Pepperflash plugin](https://blog.google/products/chrome/flash-and-chrome/). Ubuntu followed suit and disabled it. Here is the [official PR from Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/ubuntu/pepper-flash). There are old flash packages in the repo, but **they do not work for Chrome**:

- `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` - Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin (this is the Google hosted Pepperflash which they stopped hosting)
- `flashplugin-installer` - Adobe Flash Player plugin installer (this uses NPAPI which Chrome doesn't support)
- `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` - PPAPI-host NPAPI-plugin adapter for pepperflash (this isn't needed because Chrome natively supports PPAPI)
- `flashplugin-downloader` - Adobe Flash Player plugin installer (transitional package links to flashplugin-installer)

### Ubuntu Way

First we make sure we have the **partner** repository installed. If we do, this won't do anything. Then we install `adobe-flashplugin`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin;
```

Now you can go [meet Hudson he Muskox](http://www.slate.com/articles/video/video/2016/08/meet_hudson_the_muskox_at_the_point_defiance_zoo_aquarium_video.html) on like the last remaining major site to do video distribution in flash (evil eye for Slate).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson valid point! Thanks for the correction.  That method does in fact work, and I was in err. I have fixed the answer. I've also removed the other way because I think it adds confusion and offers nothing if the distro can take care of it.

Comment: Now it's better. :) Dowvote retracted. Actully `flashplugin-installer` works for its purpose in Ubuntu, i.e. installing the NPAPI plugin, which is not applicable in the answer. Would suggest that you drop `flashplugin-installer` from the list of non-working packages as well.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson that actually doesn't work for me, I'm getting [this error with it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/synaptic/+bug/1522675). The actual install doesn't work.

Comment: It's correctly installed despite of that annoying error message.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i don't think so.. I couldn't find anything anywhere that lead me to believe it actually worked. And looking at the source nothing checks the return of `install_plugin`, it just outputs `echo "Flash Plugin installed."`

Answer (score 0):

download an older version of chrome ( you need to search for an independant archive). extract pepperflash. copy it to the plugin folder for chromium.

version 58 or earlier should have pepperflash.

https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php